# How I can display string format on my Uilabel when selecting data from Uipickerview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uipickerview

> Hi I have one picker view. This picker view from web services came to
>   loading data. This picker view is 2 part. Picker view 1. part is
>   Project name. and Picker view 2. part is Project number. I want to
>   write on my label same picker view is 1. part I want to write on label
>   "A1 Unitesi", and i want to write on label2 "002" but my label on
>   write "DevamEdenProjelerObje:"0xada6fe0">why on my label  write
>   "DevamEdenProjelerObje:"0xada6fe0"> ?` Can you help to me ? How i can
>   on my label write "A1 Unitesi" ?

[image]

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
        return 2;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

        if (component == 0) {
            return [RaporlarList count];
        }
        return [RaporlarList count];

    }

    #pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

        if (component == 0) {
        eObje =  [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row];
        return  eObje.ProjeAdii;

        }
        eObje = [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row];
        return eObje.ProjeNoo;
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark PickerView Delegate

    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje Adı : %@", [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row]];
            lblProjeAdi.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", resultString];

        }
        else
        {
            NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje No: %@", [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row]];
            lblProjeNo.text = resultString;

        }

       }
```

Comment: `[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row].ProjeAdii`

Comment: you have check by nslog what value u got in resultstring and     [RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row]

Comment: OS X Tip: Hit COMMAND+SHIFT+4 and then SPACE to get a screenshot of any open window.

Comment: thank you Desdenova. your right. I should use COMMAND+SHIFT+4 and then SPACE. :)

Comment: Thank you, for your answer Jaswant Singh Rajpurohit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know if I understood well but isn't that better?

```
if (component == 0)
    {
        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje Adı : %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeAdii]];
        lblProjeAdi.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", resultString];

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Proje No: %@", [[RaporlarList objectAtIndex:row] ProjeNoo]];
        lblProjeNo.text = resultString;

    }
```

Comment: Nice to meet Vincent. Thank you very much for your answer. your answer is true. If my another question Let me ask you ?